# Chamar método em ChoiceBox

Tags: java, javafx, controles

criei um ChoiceBox, onde a cada nível selecionado, um método deveria ser chamado; mas acontece o seguinte, qualquer item selecionado chama o método; como fazer uma condição, ou seja, dependendo do item selecionado, chama um determinado método. Segue uma parte do código.

```
ChoiceBox cb = new ChoiceBox();
    cb.setId("btn_transparent_cb");
    cb.getItems().addAll("Nível 1", "Nível 2", "Nível 3", "Nível 4");
    //cb.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();


    cb.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty()
    .addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
      @Override
      public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Number value, Number new_value) {

        exemploMetodo();
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi, pessoal; obrigado. Segue a solução:

```
 cb.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener((obs, old , newValue)->{
        switch(newValue.intValue()){
            case 0:
                metodoUm();
                break;
            case 1:
                metodoDois();
                break;
            case 2:
                metodoTres();
                break;
        }
    });
```